# Calculating the PMF of roll-and-keep dice (XdZkY)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I've been trying to use the PMF shown in an older question, found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/relevancy-of-order-statistics-to-the-roll-and-keep-dice-mechanic), and sourced from [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=2813034), but I've run into a problem. When attempting to calculate N, I'm finding that B (using s+i+j-x-ry = B) rapidly becomes negative when keeping more than 1 die (y>1). This, in turn, results in attempting to distribute a negative number of "balls". This is a bit out of my depth, since I'm not very experienced with combinatorics, but as far as I know I understand all the operations I'm trying to perform. What am I missing in using this?

I'm not sure what to make of the modifications from the original Physics Forum version to the version in the question. I've been using the original Physics Forum one, where they differ, but at the moment my problem lies in a part that seems to be identical.

Comment: I suggest you don't try to distribute fewer than 1 ball. What does negative balls mean in terms of the original problem?

Comment: What it seems to mean, if I'm reading the original post correctly, is that I'm requiring a negative number of dice to roll a result of r in order to produce a sum s, which is obviously impossible. This seems to occur because r*y grows much faster than s+i+j when y > 1. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to set up the indices in such a way as to avoid this situation, or define such cases as equal to 0, without violating any assumptions.

Comment: Doesn't "don't do things with fewer than one ball/die" cover it?

Comment: If by that you mean setting it so that if that situation would occur, you assign that outcome zero probability, it doesn't seem to. I do get an outcome, but it's clearly wrong (in particular, an odd sum on all the dice seems to have significantly lower probability than an even sum). At this point, I've largely given up on this avenue and am sticking with straightforward simulation of the dice for now. Thanks for your help, though.