# Formula for dropping 2 dice (non-brute force)

Tags: distributions, combinatorics, dice, probability-generating-fn

This is a follow up from my previous question: [Formula for dropping dice (non-brute force)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/formula-for-dropping-dice-non-brute-force)
which asked how to determine the statistics for dropping the lowest die but now I'm asking how to determine the statistics when the lowest 2 dice are dropped.

So given XdY drop the lowest 2 where X is an integer of the number of dice (and is at least 3) and Y is an integer of the number of sides that the dice have (and is at least 2) what are the frequencies and probabilities (a probability mass function?) of each sum of the remaining dice? The formula must be better than O(n<sup>2</sup>) because it must be better than brute force.

Here are 2 test cases. Given 3d4 drop lowest 2 (a simple case):

```
Sum   Frequency   Probability
1     1           0.0156250000
2     7           0.1093750000
3     19          0.2968750000
4     37          0.5781250000
```

Which has a mean of 3.44 and standard deviation of 0.747.

Given 7d9 drop lowest 2 (a stress test):

```
Sum   Frequency   Probability
5     1           0.0000002091
6     7           0.0000014635
7     28          0.0000058541
8     84          0.0000175623
9     210         0.0000439058
10    470         0.0000982653
11    966         0.0002019666
12    1848        0.0003863709
13    3325        0.0006951749
14    5670        0.0011854561
15    9234        0.0019306000
16    14441       0.0030192544
17    21777       0.0045530297
18    31724       0.0066327003
19    44723       0.0093504683
20    61153       0.0127855731
21    81284       0.0169944652
22    105133      0.0219806986
23    132412      0.0276840598
24    162491      0.0339728315
25    194405      0.0406452561
26    226842      0.0474270270
27    258181      0.0539792334
28    286545      0.0599094412
29    310100      0.0648342065
30    327041      0.0683761488
31    335720      0.0701907121
32    335090      0.0700589947
33    324835      0.0679149290
34    305088      0.0637863218
35    276921      0.0578973019
36    242060      0.0506087328
37    202825      0.0424056689
38    161882      0.0338455047
39    122101      0.0255282859
40    85849       0.0179488933
41    55426       0.0115881997
42    32011       0.0066927049
43    15750       0.0032929337
44    5915        0.0012366796
45    1401        0.0002929143
```

Which has a mean of 30.56 and a standard deviation of 5.490. For comparison making this table using JavaScript brute force in Chrome took me 11 seconds.

I will accept a formula that only outputs probability but prefer one that only outputs frequency. If the formula can't be generalized into XdY drop Z then I'll ask follow up question(s) until I can get a formula for XdY drop Z (I couldn't figure out how to generalize the formula from my previous question).

Just like before I am a programmer not a statistician. It took me a while to figure out how to read each answer to my previous question. So please explain your answer plainly and show the steps taken (or better yet use well-written pseudo-code).

For reference the formula for dropping 1 die can be found here: [Formula for dropping dice (non-brute force)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/formula-for-dropping-dice-non-brute-force/242857#242857) which I implemented in JavaScript here: https://github.com/SkySpiral7/Dice/blob/7e9c69b247aeb6ef95e1f1ca2962cb52cea4c5de/src/main/javascript/beta/StackExchangeWhuber.js

Side question:
The side bar linked me to [Relevancy of order statistics to the roll-and-keep dice mechanic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/relevancy-of-order-statistics-to-the-roll-and-keep-dice-mechanic) which I don't really understand and while it is a formula for exactly what I want, the quadruple summations and choose functions make me think that it is far more computationally expensive than what I'm hoping for. Can this function be improved or is it more efficient than it looks? Otherwise I'll continue down this path of looking for an efficient formula. If this side question should instead be a full question (rather than a discussion in comments) then let me know.